# Is Marshal.AllocHGlobal() result deterministic?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

Let's say I have this code:

```
IntPtr native_color = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (Gdk.RGBA)));
```

Is the memory of native_color all initialized to zeros? You would think yes, but there are some of the cases in which I've detected that it is not the case... So, is Marshal.AllocHGlobal() not deterministic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Marshal.AllocHGlobal Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx)

> When AllocHGlobal calls LocalAlloc, it passes a LMEM_FIXED flag, which
>   causes the allocated memory to be locked in place. Also, the allocated
>   memory **is not zero-filled**.

If you have seen that the memory returned by Marshal.AllocHGlobal was filled with zeros, it is probably because they were already there.

Comment: +1 You want me to read the documentation? Where do you get these crazy ideas?

Comment: oops sorry I got confused when I landed in this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal.aspx and I didn't see more explanations, obviously I had to choose the correct overload... thanks